# Finding all occurrences of a word in a string in Python3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to find all words containing "hell" in 1 sentence. There are 3 occurrences in the below string. But re.search is returning only the first 2 occurrences. I tried both findall and search. Can someone please tell me what is wrong here ?

```
>>> s = 'heller pond hell hellyi'
>>> m = re.findall('(hell)\S*', s)
>>> m.group(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'group'
>>> m = re.search('(hell)\S*', s)
>>> m.group(0)
'heller'
>>> m.group(1)
'hell'
>>> m.group(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: no such group
>>>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` and search for `hell` with zero or more word characters on either side:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'heller pond hell hellyi'
>>> re.findall('\w*hell\w*', s)
['heller', 'hell', 'hellyi']
>>>
```

Comment: This one works perfect. Do you know why this is wrong ?
>>> m = re.search('(hell)\S*', s). I returns only the first 2 occurances. "hellyi" is not returned.

Comment: No, it is not returning two occurrences.  `re.search` only gets the first.  You are getting `hell` because that is the value matched by the capture group.  It is still a part of `heller` though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use str.split and see if the substring is in each word:

```
s = 'heller pond hell hellyi'

print([w for w in s.split() if "hell" in w])
```

Comment: Thanks ! Is there a way to do it via regular expressions ? I am still learning it and really want to try it using RE.

Comment: @Vin, yes Icodez answer simply using findall will work. If you don't care about efficiency use a regex

Answer (score 2):

Your regex isn't finding `hell` because you're only matching `hell` that precedes some other non-space character. Instead just look for a literal `hell` -- nothing fancy.

```
In [3]: re.findall('hell', 'heller pond hell hellyi')
Out[3]: ['hell', 'hell', 'hell']
```

**EDIT**

Per your comment, you want to return the whole word if it's found in the middle of the word. In which case you should use the `*` zero-or-or more quantifier.

```
In [4]: re.findall(r"\S*hell\S*", 'heller pond hell hellyi')
Out[4]: ['heller', 'hell', 'hellyi']
```

In other words:

```
re.compile(r"""
    \S*          # zero or more non-space characters
    hell         # followed by a literal hell
    \S*          # followed by zero or more non-space characters""", re.X)
```

Note that Padraic's answer is definitely the BEST way to go about this:

```
[word for word in "heller pond hell hellyi".split() if 'hell' in word]
```

Comment: But I want it to return "heller", "hell", "hellyi". So I have to give \S or some other escape char.

Comment: the "in" operator will give you those

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's me but i use regex very little. Python3 has extensive text functions, what is wrong with using the build-in function ?

```
'heller pond hell hellyi'.count('hell')
```

The only drawback i see is that this way i never really learn to use regex. :-)